# Passing variables in the permalink structure on a custom post type

Tags: rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag, query-variable

I have a structure like this for my custom post types:

domain.com/member/member-name/book/book-name

Basically, I have a custom post type of member, and the member-name is the post. What I want to do is pass a variable called books, but I can't get my code to work.

I've based my solution on one that has previously been asked on here but my structure is different, and I've googled and googled to no avail. I really cant get my head around rewrite structures either!

```
    function add_book_rewrite() {
        add_rewrite_tag('%book_name%','([^&]+)');
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'add_book_rewrite' );

    function add_book_rewrite_rules() {
        add_rewrite_rule('^member/([^/]*)/book/([^/]*)/?','index.php?post_type=member&name=$matches[2]&book_name=$matches[4]','top');
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'add_book_rewrite_rules' );

    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_var' );

    function add_query_var( $query_vars ) {

        $query_vars[] = 'book_name';
        return $query_vars;
    }

    echo 'Book is '.get_query_var('book_name');
```

Any pointers on this would be received with gratitude

Thanks

Comment: Did this ever get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, adding a rewrite tag and a query var is redundant, adding the tag adds the query var.

Second, `$matches` corresponds to each regex pattern you have in your rule, so it should be `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]`, not 2 and 4.

Last, for a single `member`, you can just set the `member` query var.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^member/([^/]*)/book/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?member=$matches[1]&book_name=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

Untested, but should get you going in the right direction. Also check out this [rewrite analyzer plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) to help you construct your rewrite rule.